# ITHit Ajax Browser upload cancel issue, truncated file left on server

Tags: ajax, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

If user cancel an upload in Ajax Browser it seems as if a partial file is left on server. I would expect that partially uploaded files are deleted. Is there a solution to this? or is it possible to remove the cancel option in UI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the Cancel item from upload panel context menu. Please use following code:

```
ITHit.Events.AddListener(ajaxFileBrowser.GetMenuManager(), 'OnShowMenu', onShowMenu);

...

function onShowMenu(menu, aContextMenuHierarchyItems) {
    if (menu.Id == 'UploadProgressPanelMenu'){  
        var index = getMenuIndexByMenuId(menu, 'CancelUpload');
           if (index != -1) {
           menu.Children.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

function getMenuIndexByMenuId(menu, menuId) {
    for (var i = 0, l = menu.Children.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (menu.Children[i].Id == menuId) {
           return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/context_menu_customization) you can find more information about menu customization. The context menu IDs (like 'CancelUpload' in the above example) are located in ITHitAJAXFileBrowser.js, you can easily find them among Phrases block, this part of code is not minified. The top level menu IDs (like the 'UploadProgressPanelMenu') are listed [here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/settings_reference) in Menu object description.

If you are using IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine on server side, you can delete the file in [IResumableUpload.CancelUpload](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/default.aspx?main=http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.ResumableUpload.IResumableUpload.CancelUpload.html) implementation. Note that as soon as cancel upload command is asynchronous operation the upload may continue and your file may be blocked in your storage.

Because Cancel upload is asynchronous, this is the reason why Ajax File Browser can not delete the file directly during Cancel upload execution. The file is in most cases blocked on server side by upload.